# connection timing out using ssh - "steps to take"?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I can ssh to the server using another machine with an ecdsa key, and that is set up just fine. 
I generated an ecdsa key on another machine and did a cat of the ecdsa public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` in my home directory on the server.

When I try to ssh to the server it is timing out on the new machine, not prompting a password.

the key permissions are set to `-rw-------`

I did a `cat /var/log/auth.log`, but nothing is showing in relation to this. Where to look next?

Answer (score 1):

Try **-vvv**, like ssh user@machine -vvv

Also, assuming you CAN connect via SSH with another ID ssh-copy-id is a easy way to send the right info up to the target.

Comment: Thanks. I did ssh-copy-id to make sure the right key was sent to the target. I did -vvv and it came up with "needpriv 0". I am on the same (home) network and the setup from what I can tell is exactly the same as the other machine so I'm not sure where to look next.